# Typescript union types not excluded

Tags: typescript, union-types, typescript4.0

I have an issue with union types and `Exclude` ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/FAFwngDgpgBQYgewTAvDA3sABFgJgQxHwC4YBnEAJwEsA7AcwG5ssEQALKSgEUJJloBXALYAjLswC+zcNCwAhfJSwosAeWHUQAHkQIANAHI2nHn0MA+YAHprWWbEWVUWdHj7EsFGg0ZZpWLZYAKIAblC09uzUZFgxWLRsWADuCJQA1nT0oJCwek6o8EgwAD4wTsw5cgDK7AiCADa48lB6KiEAHgDGDYK4ULpITvoKShZ+QQBySakZWVVQWLX1TS1O7cHdvf2DCMNYeuOBdtUIwlB1ySlpmQxAA)):

```js
type Foo = {
  data: string;
  otherData: number;
};
type Bar = Omit<Foo,'otherData'>
// type Bar = { data: string; }; // Even this is not working
type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

type ShouldBeFoo = Exclude<FooBar, Bar>; // Not working
// ShouldBeFoo = never

type ShouldBeBar = Exclude<FooBar, Foo>; // Somehow working
// ShouldBeBar = { data: string }
```

Am I missing something related to union types and/or `Exclude`?

I also tried with TS 4.4 and 4.2 with the same result.

---

**Note:**

We discovered the issue using type guards, you can see it in the [playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#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-qwAAM0cHocG1PZKG03B5vDZg-osAB3djUVy2LSBdgIQSuXBYcQhqOtZxxzoJuTNPTBlho3WXL20FlAA).

Comment: I note that TypeScript's type-system, while expressive, is **not sound**, [by-design](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9825), I suspect you've stumbled over one of their edge-cases.

Answer (score 1):

Utility types like `Pick`, `Omit` work well with interface or types with properties since the second arg looks of `keyof K`.

As yours is a union type, the TS compiler is unable to infer the correct behavior. You can try this

```
type Foo = {
    data: string;
    otherData: number;
};

type Bar = Omit<Foo, 'otherData'>

type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

type Reduce<T, K> = T extends K ? K : never;

type ShouldBeFoo = Reduce<FooBar, Foo>;
type ShouldBeBar = Reduce<FooBar, Bar>;
```

Comment: Actually, that is the exact definition of `Exclude`, just renamed to `Reduce` ^^

Comment: @phry Exclude is `T extends K ? never : T`

Comment: Yes, and yours is the exact definition of `ExcludeExact`. One question though, when I use `Exclude` in place of `Reduce` why doesn't it work?

Comment: You confused me. Got it.

Comment: FYI: Reduce helper you've created is already implemented in TS as [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).

Comment: Okay, This was insightful. Thanks @raina77ow

Answer (score 1):

Exclude excludes types that are *matching*, not *equal*.

You are excluding `Bar` from `FooBar`. `Bar` matches `Bar` and `Bar` matches `Foo`. So you exclude both.

You could use something such as

```
type ExcludeExact<T, U> = T extends U ? U extends T ? T : never : never
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the real issue is misunderstanding how `extends` check works in TS. [Quoting the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

> ```
> SomeType extends OtherType ? TrueType : FalseType;
> ```
>
> When the type on the left of the extends is **assignable** to the one on
> the right, then you’ll get the type in the first branch (the “true”
> branch); otherwise you’ll get the type in the latter branch (the
> “false” branch).

In this case, SomeType doesn't have to be an explicit extension of OtherType (in `class SomeType extends OtherType` sense): it's enough for `SomeType` to be **assignable** to `OtherType`, to have all the properties (of the same type) as `OtherType`.

As a side effect, when type `Y` is a result of `Omit<X, ...>`, `X extends Y` check always passes (!), as `Omit` only reduces the number of properties, but doesn't change their types and/or create new ones:

```
type Omit<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P]; }
```

Now, as `Exclude` generic actually looks like this:

```
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T
```

... your union type (of `Foo | Bar`) passes `extends Bar` check just fine, as both parts of union pass it. However, `Bar extends Foo` check fails, that's why your expression works fine for `shouldBeBar` case.